# NSMutableArray 'addObject:' Crashing iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

This is my error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Both the array (which is NSMutableArray) and the object being added are definitely not nil, and the @property for the array is straight up (nonatomic, retain).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are the array is not a NSMutableArray - a NSArray is not mutable, that is, you cannot add objects to it.

I know you said it is - but if you do

```
NSMutableArray* someArray = [NSArray array];
```

you get a NSArray, not a NSMutableArray. I've done it.

Comment: Sorry, one thing I forgot to mention in the question; I can always add one object, the second one crashes it. Always, exactly like that.

Comment: You need to post more code. Does the array go out of scope between additions? Are you using code like "myArray = [NSMutableArray array]" or "self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array]"? If the former, you must use self. for the retain to take effect.

Comment: My problem ended up being that I needed that, goddamn, mutableCopy, not copy. Cheers for the help.

Comment: Assigning an NSMutableArray object to a variable with the type NSArray shouldn't cause this issue, right?